vertical scrollbar showing up even when total height is 100%
I have simple HTML/CSS code, that have 3 divs , Header, content and footer.Header and footer are of fixed height(170px) and content is expected to take remaining vertical space. all threes are placed vertically with the help of diplay:flex and content block is forced to take remaining space with flex-grow:1.
The problem is appearance of vertical scrollbar. I am not able to understand why it is happening as according to my understanding, total height will always be  [170px + (atmost remaining) + 170px] , that will always be 100%.
Code:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  height: 170px;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightpink;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 170px;
}
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">this is header</div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis,
  </div>
  <div class="footer">This is footer</div>
</div>



Someone help me understand why it is happening,also the correct way to achieve the required result.
I have tried adding overflow:hidden to body , but i don't think that is best way to do it, as it is clipping the overflow.

Converted your code to an executable snippet, but that does not appear to reproduce the issue? Does this occur in any particular browser?

You want scrollbar or not and if its no then we cannot reproduce your issue as there is no scrollbar already.

The problem was apparently happening due to Live server VS code extension, when i opened html file directly there was no vertical scrollbar.

.content {
  background-color: lightpink;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

have a try
